# makefile calling itself

Tags: makefile

When a makefile calls itself like

```
test : 
    @ mv $(BIN_SRC) $(BIN_SCR_TMP)
    @ mv $(BIN_TEST_SRC) $(BIN_TEST_SRC_TMP)
    @ make runtest
    @ mv $(BIN_SCR_TMP) $(BIN_SRC)
    @ mv $(BIN_TEST_SRC_TMP) $(BIN_TEST_SRC)

runtest : $(OBJS) $(LIB)
    g++ -o $(TEST_BIN_FILE) $(OBJS) $(LIB)
    @ chmod ugo+x $(TEST_BIN_FILE)
    $(TEST_BIN_FILE)
```

and you run `make test` it prints this out to the terminal:

```
make test

make[1]: Entering directory `/users/home2/admin/stringha/cs240/webcrawler'
g++ -o bin/webcrawler-tests  obj/URL.o  obj/webcrawler-tests.o lib/libcs240utils.a bin/webcrawler-tests
Hello webcrawler test!
make[1]: Leaving directory `/users/home2/admin/stringha/cs240/webcrawler'
```

I was wondering how to make it not print out the lines

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/users/home2/admin/stringha/cs240/webcrawler'
```

and

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/users/home2/admin/stringha/cs240/webcrawler'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add --no-print-directory to MAKEFLAGS:

```
$ export MAKEFLAGS=--no-print-directory
```

or add that option to your invocation of make:

```
$ make test --no-print-directory
```

Answer (score 6):

Add [`--no-print-directory` flag](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#g_t_002dw-Option):

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory
```

Or add it to the sub-make invocation command directly:

```
test :
    ...
    @$(MAKE) runtest --no-print-directory
    ...
```

Read also about using [`MAKE` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable).